# Building a pie plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a pie plot of a categorical variable "Reclaim". There are 8 categories in this variable. I have written this code:

```
 data.plot.pie(y='Reclaim', figsize=(5, 5))
```

There is an error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"
Could you please explain me what is not supported here? What is the problem here? How does the int comes into play as I am dealing purely with str categories?

Here is a paste from my Jupyter notebook:

```
> import pandas as pd
> data=pd.read_csv("reclaims1.txt")
> data.head()
> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 RangeIndex: 122 entries, 0 to 121
 Data columns (total 3 columns): 
 Reclaim 122 non-null object
  Person 122 non-null object
  Processing time 122 non-null float64
 dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
 memory usage: 2.9+ KB
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline data.plot.pie(y='Reclaim', figsize=(5, 5))
```

Here's some sample data:

```
       data['Reclaim'].head(5)
        0    Account closing
        1               IBAN
        2        Status info
        3           Matching
        4            Billing
        Name: Reclaim, dtype: object
```

I would like to see the percentage of accurance of e.g. "IBAN"
category from the dataset on a pie chart. There are 8 categories in
total. I would like to see how often they are presented there.

Comment: The error message quite simply means you are trying to create a numeric plot of something which isn't a number. Maybe you have inconsistencies in your data, or maybe you are pulling out the wrong column, or maybe you need to process it into a form where what you pass to the plot is the actual numbers you want to see in the plot.

Comment: So how do you expect Matploitlib to visualize "IBAN" as a percentage? A human can come up with at least one good hypothesis but Matplotlib is not AI, you have to give it numbers.

Comment: [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html)'s how it should look, for it to work. You need a column with numbers and one with names, for each section of you pie chart. Then you call the column with the numbers.

Comment: Thank you George, now I see, the pie plot is for numerical values, I cannot just use the categorical variable without doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) first. Try:

```
data.Reclaim.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5, 5))
```